# Using CMS on Mongo Database

Tags: drupal, mongodb, joomla

I am planning to use MongoDB for building a CMS application. The two choice for CMS platforms being Joomla and Drupal. while Drupal seems to have http://drupal.org/project/mongodb support. I was not able to find good support for Joomla. Can anyone share your experience/thoughts of using Joomla on MongoDB ?

Comment: This is probably question you should ask on the Joomla dev google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/joomla-dev-general

As far as I could see there is no implementation / driver MongoDB on Joomla.

Here is a CMS that uses MongoDB: http://calip.so/

Answer (score 0):

For Joomla have a look at:

- [Joomla and Mongodb](http://de.slideshare.net/spacemonkeylabs/joomla-and-mongodb) (a bit old)
- [sml4joomla libraries](https://github.com/spacemonkey/sml4joomla)